# xhtml2pdf gae no module named

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to deploy app on GAE. On local the app works, but on GAE when I try to run, return:

no module named xhtml2pdf

Thats the code:

```
import webapp2
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from weasyprint import HTML
import urllib
import urllib2
import StringIO
```

The requeriments.txt:

```
Pillow
html2pdf
xhtml2pdf
pyPdf
webapp2
webob
Paste
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read and followed the docs for installing/including 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Another thing to note in standard appengine (not VM's) Pillow won't run.

Comment: PIL is already available on App Engine so you do not need to include Pillow, webapp2, or webob in your `lib` folder when you follow the [installing 3rd party libraries guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring).

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy xhtml2pdf and other dependent files to the project.

1) Copy xhtml2pdf, html5lib, reportlab folder to pdf folder.

2) Copy six.py file to pdf folder.

For more detail check this blog
http://array151.blogspot.in/2016/05/how-to-get-xhtml2pdf-working-on-google.html